# OR-Tools Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type '...' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, or-tools

When Trying to run the sample: [VrpTimeWindows](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/VrpTimeWindows.cs) of [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/), the following code block generate an error:

```
int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
      (long fromIndex, long toIndex) => {
        // Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
        var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
        return data.GetTimeMatrix()[fromNode, toNode]; }
    );
```

> Error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'SWIGTYPE_p_std__functionT_long_long_flong_long_long_longF_t' because
>   it is not a delegate type

I am using the latest version available: [7.0-beta.1](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/tag/v7.0-beta.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest available version ([7.0-beta.1](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/tag/v7.0-beta.1)) does not yet support using the lambda expression as an argument to the transit call back function. However, it is [committed to the code repository](https://github.com/google/or-tools/commit/54e38c692a94b52b8c7ee37bb50089f759905eae) and will be available in the next version.

For now, till a new release is available, there are two possible solutions:

- The first solution is that you can download the latest version of
  OR-Tools and compile it on your machine following [those
  instructions](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/dotnet/) for installing from Source.
- The second solution is by replacing the argument with an instance of
  a derived class from `Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.LongLongToLong`
  as following:

  ```
      LongLongToLong timeCallback = new TimeCallback(data, manager);

      int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(timeCallback);
  ```

Where `TimeCallback` class could have the following implementation:

```
class TimeCallback : LongLongToLong
{
    private long[,] timeMatrix;
    private RoutingIndexManager indexManager;
    public TimeCallback(DataModel data, RoutingIndexManager manager)
    {
        timeMatrix = data.GetTimeMatrix();
        indexManager = manager;
    }

    override public long Run(long fromIndex, long toIndex)
    {
        // Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        int fromNode = indexManager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
        int toNode = indexManager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
        return timeMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
    }
}
```

---

Note: For `LongLongToLong timeCallback = new TimeCallback(Data, manager);`
the Garbage Collector can destroy this object since register does not keep it alive in C# (note: this will be changed in final 7.0 using delegate and correctly managing ownership). To avoid GC, you have to place a call to `GC.KeepAlive` on the `TimeCallback` object after `SolveWithParameters` method.

---

Here is a sample of using the above: https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/workforce-distribution-sample/